# How to send dao object to new thread in Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have some manager, where I have `userDao`, which is set by

```
@Autowired
public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
}
```

I want start new thread in manager and pass this dao in constructor.
Like this:

```
new MyThread(userDao).start();
```

It is safe? Or possible? If no, how can I do this?

Thank you for your replye.

Comment: Why do you want to pass the existing dao in, instead of using spring in `MyThread` to do injection?

Comment: I need do some hard/long code on background

Comment: Have you considered using spring's "@Async" or Java's ExecutorService?

Comment: bart.s nope, When i call method with @async is a like a call new thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that accepts your DAO as a parameter. Annotate the function with @Aysnc

When calling the function keep in mind the following:

- When you call an Async annotated function from within the same class the call will be synchronous (this is to do with proxied objects)
- Async methods will not participate in the same transaction context as the caller

This approach encourages you to think about your class structure and is to be encouraged. For instance you might want to also wrap it with @Retryable in the case of failure.

Of course, you also do something like

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
MyWorker worker = new MyWorker(UserDao userDao);
executorService.submit(worker);

private class MyWorker implements Callable {
    private UserDao userDao 
    MyWorker(UserDao userDao){
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    public void call() {
        .. do something
    }
}
```

But that's a lot more code.